# Output only some part of a log line using grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have lines like these -

```
/mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-21.log.gz:2019-08-21 07:31:14,153 5458142 [XNIO-3 task-4] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.ws.FileManger [FileName.java:1838] - UUIDs in this bucket 8501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
/mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-21.log.gz:2019-08-21 07:31:14,153 5458144 [XNIO-3 task-4] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.ws.FileManger [FileName.java:1838] - UUIDs in this bucket 6501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
```

What I ultimately need to do is, collect all the UUIDs and prepare an SQL insert statement like this -

```
insert into sometable (uuid) values ("6501792126581991569","8073766106536916628")..(..);
```

There are huge number of such lines, almost 500k. I am unable to apply regex by opening the file in my sublime text editor.

So, I am trying it via grep.

I tried this -

```
zgrep "UUIDs in this bucket" /mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-2* | grep -Eo ".* UUIDs in this bucket(.*)" | cut -d: -f5
```

It printed more than what I needed -

```
1838] - UUIDs in this bucket 8501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
```

How do I pick only from the UUIDs?

**Update**

Corrected sql query syntax -

```
insert into sometable (uuid) values ("6501792126581991569"),("8073766106536916628")..(..);
```

Comment: Do you just want the UUIDs with the commas inbetween?

Comment: And do you want all UUIDs or only two as you show in your insert statement?

Comment: I want all the UUIDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all of the numbers after `UUIDs in this bucket`, you can use `sed` like so:

```
$ zcat file.gz | sed -n 's/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //p' 
8501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
6501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
```

Or, use perl and output the full SQL statement:

```
$ zcat file.gz | perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){@uuids=split(/,/); $k{$_}++ for @uuids} END{ print "insert into sometable (uuid) values (" , join ",",map{qq/"$_"/} keys(%k); print ");\n"}' 
insert into sometable (uuid) values ("6135982080116553120","4830289023695906800","8501792126581991569","9040948912536460872","7661719762428556576","8471856544054164043","8306484440313978157","6501792126581991569","5431263453539111247","8073766106536916628");
```

Or, slightly more legibly:

```
$ zcat file.gz | 
    perl -ne 'chomp;
              if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){
                @uuids=split(/,/); 
                $k{$_}++ for @uuids
              }
              END{
                print "insert into sometable (uuid) values (" , 
                           join ",",map{qq/"$_"/} @uuids; 
                print ");\n"
            }'
insert into sometable (uuid) values ("6501792126581991569","8073766106536916628","4830289023695906800","6135982080116553120","8306484440313978157","9040948912536460872","8471856544054164043","5431263453539111247","7661719762428556576");
```

Comment: Bang on! Just a little modification, to do a single insert query, to avoid too many inserts - `perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){@uuids=split(/,/); print "," , join ",",map{qq/"$_"/} @uuids; print "\n"}'`

Comment: @SandeepanNath ah yes, good point. Please see updated answer. It now dedupes the UUIDs and only prints a single insert statement.

Comment: or use perl's `DBI` module to connect to the sql database and actually run the sql statement.   Also, `perl's PerlIO::gzip` module can be used to read files whether they're compressed or not.

Comment: @cas all true, but I felt that's kind of beyond the scope of the question :).

Comment: @terdon a little more help needed. For the single insert query to work, I need it to be like  `values ("6501792126581991569"),("8073766106536916628")..` - Notice each of the UUIDs wrapped in single brackets, which I missed in my question.

Comment: DBI is certainly out of scope for this question, but being able to read gzipped files without zcat is, IMO, within scope (similar to "you don't need to pipe from sed into perl" would be in scope). worth mentioning in a comment if not implementing, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing/able to use tools other than `grep` you could do it with `awk` fairly easily since it looks like you always want the end of the line.  You can have it print only the last field like:

```
zcat /mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-2* | awk '/UUIDs in this bucket/ {print $NF}'
```

I don't know if any forms of `zgrep` don't support Perl style regex, but assuming yours does too you could do it with that like

```
zgrep -Po 'UUIDs in this bucket \K.*' /mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-2*
```

since the `\K` tells the pattern to not count everything before it as part of the match.  So this will only print the things that come after the match.

Comment: The \K from the 2nd solution did it for me. Although the exact solution you provided did not work, as I still got some parts of the lines before the "UUIDs in this bucket" section. This is what worked for me - `zgrep 'UUIDs in this bucket' /mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-2* | grep -oP ".* UUIDs in this bucket \K.*"`

Comment: As far as I know, most (all?) grep implementations other than GNU grep have neither `-P` nor `-o`. This will work fine for GNU grep, but you might want to point that limitation out.

Comment: @terdon fair enough, but since he used `-o` in the question I felt it was probably safe to include that sort of answer

Comment: @EricRenouf oh, absolutely! This is the sort of thing I would have done too! I only commented because you'd written "I don't know if any forms of `zgrep` don't support Perl style regex", so I thought I'd point out that most don't :)

Answer (score 0):

Another `perl` way to generate the SQL code:

```
zcat -f /mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-2* |
  perl -lne 'BEGIN{$"=q(",")}
             @u = m{(?:UUIDs in this bucket |\G,)\K\d+}g;
             print qq(insert into sometable (uuid) values ("@u");) if @u'
```